# How can I create unique permissions on SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, user

can I create unique permissions for certain areas on SharePoint without breaking Inheritance.

Comment: you will need to break inheritance for creating unique permissions

Comment: Yes, only way is to create different site collections for your areas!

Answer (score 0):

The only way this can be done, is if those unique permissions are set from the parent of whatever you are trying to secure. However, this most certainly means breaking permissions inheritance on the parent object itself.

So as an example, lets say Group A has read permission to my site but there is a list where users are to submit some information. Their read permission will not allow this, so you could either up their site permission or break inheritance on the list. By breaking inheritance on the list, you can then alter Group A to have a higher permission level there, and only there, so they can submit information. Everywhere else remains read only because it inherits permission from the parent object (the site).

The other way, if you don't want to break permissions, would be to come up with some sort of user control that boots the user out of whatever they were trying to access. This wouldn't necessarily be robust as there would be other ways to get at the data outside of the user control. It is basically security though obscurity.

Comment: If I use unique permissions further down and break inheritance , will any changes I do say in a read-only group cascade down to inheritance broken permissions group that has this group in before the break. sorry if it is silly question just need to cover the permissions as robust as I can before Go live of our project

Comment: updated with an example, hope that helps.

Comment: If i'm understanding your question right, yes, if you make changes (i.e. adding and removing users) to the group the group changes will apply even if the group is attached to a list with broken inheritance.  This is the advantage to using groups versus adding users directly to the resource/list.